# Using Guzzle to call Stackoverflow api is not working

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-4, guzzle

I am using  Guzzle to work with the Stackoverflow API . My code is as follows

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced',['pagesize'=>'2','order'=>'desc','sort'=> 'activity','q'=>['laravel eloquent'],'site'=>'stackoverflow'])->send();
```

but I am getting this excpetion

> InvalidArgumentException No method is configured to handle the
>   pagesize config key

the complete url (on stackoverflow) that works is [posted here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#pagesize=2&order=desc&sort=activity&q=laravel%20eloquent&filter=default&site=stackoverflow). Note you will need to run it.

Can you please help me out with this , please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters), you need to add `query` key:

```
$parameters = ['pagesize'=>'2','order'=>'desc','sort'=> 'activity','q'=>['laravel eloquent'],'site'=>'stackoverflow'];
$response = $client->get('api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced',['query' => $parameters ])->send();
```

Comment: now I am getting this error message : GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException
cURL error 3: <url> malformed